# Python3 porting: TypeError: unorderable types: dict() < int()

Tags: python, python-3.x, porting

I have this piece of code that is working fine in python 2.7.
"dist" is a dictionary of number and "min_dist" is just a number.

```
for v in vertices:
    if dist[v.node_id] < min_dist:
        min_dist = dist[v.node_id]
        cur_min = v
```

Now I am trying to run it under python 3.2 and it gives me this error:

```
    if dist[v.node_id] < min_dist:
TypeError: unorderable types: dict() < int()
```

What is wrong with my code in python 3.2?

Comment: if dist[v.node_id] is a dictionary, you can replace `if dist[v.node_id] < min_dist:` with `if False:` and the program should still work. And if it does, you can of course remove that whole block as it never gets executed.

Comment: Ah, this part of code does get executed but there is a piece of code somewhere else that initializes (incorrectly) the dist[v.node_id] with { } and hence the problem. All the other parts of code does the initialization properly with a number.

Comment: I had exactly the same bug show up in exactly the same way, so you're not alone ;-)  Seeing this allowed me to fix it quickly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dist` is not a "dictionary of number", it is a dictionary of *dictionaries of* numbers. Your code should not work even in 2.x.

Comment: Yes, my code does work in python 2.7. I have just confirmed it again.

Comment: Then you've goofed up the porting elsewhere.

Comment: You are right. I messed up somewhere else. The code still "works" in 2.7 because of the reason explained by Lennart.

Comment: Hahaha... It happens to give me the correct result even with this problem and only in python3 the problem becomes more apparent. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 10):

Your code is "wrong" in Python 2 as well. It makes no sense to compare a dictionary to an integer. It's like asking if a color is bigger than a number, it simply makes no sense.

Python 2 allows comparisons of different types like this, and will always say that a dictionary is larger than a number, which is arbitrary. Even an empty dictionary is larger than a number:

```
>>> import sys
>>> {} > sys.maxint
True
```

Such a comparison is meaningless, and Python 3 instead correctly raises and error, in effect saying "I have no idea what you mean", which is much better and avoids mistaken comparisons.

Comment: Thanks. Your explanation helped me find the source of the problem.